# How do I select this input according to this span's value?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I have this `<span>What's your name?</span>` where I'd like to select the input[@placeholder='Insira sua resposta'] (see below HTML) but I don't know how get from the span to there. I couldn't back from span to the top shared parent of the span and the input. I've tried: `//div[@class="office-form-question-content office-form-theme-focus-border"]/*/span[.="What\'s your name?"]'` but return null. I tried back from span to top div by `//span[.="What\'s your name?"]/../*/div[@class="office-form-question-content office-form-theme-focus-border"]'` doesn't work either. How can I do that?

The HTML:

```html
<div class="office-form-question-content office-form-theme-focus-border">
  <div aria-live="assertive" role="alert"></div>
  <div class="question-title-box">
    <div>
      <div aria-level="2" class="office-form-question-title" id="question1-title" role="heading"><span class="ordinal-number">1.</span><span>What's your name?</span><span class="required-star"></span>
        <div><span class="accessibility-reader-no-display" id="question1-required">Requer resposta</span></div>
        <div><span class="accessibility-reader-no-display" id="question1-questiontype">Texto de linha única</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="office-form-question-element">
    <div class="student-feedback-view-short-text-field-with-correctness">
      <div>
        <div class="office-form-textfield"><input class="office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control border-no-radius" aria-labelledby="question1-title question1-required question1-questiontype" placeholder="Insira sua resposta" spellcheck="true" maxlength="4000"
            value=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may very well be a faster, easier way of doing this, but I learned XPath in the bad old 1.0 days, so that's what I know. In the XPath below I'm getting the `span` with the content, using the `ancestor` axis to go up to the containing `div`, then descending back to the `input`. The `document.evaluate` and `iterateNext` is just to demonstrate it working.

```js
var input = document.evaluate(`//span[text() = "What's your name?"]/ancestor::div[@class="office-form-question-content office-form-theme-focus-border"]//input[@class="office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control border-no-radius"]`, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
console.log(input.iterateNext());
```

```html
<div class="office-form-question-content office-form-theme-focus-border">
  <div aria-live="assertive" role="alert"></div>
  <div class="question-title-box">
    <div>
      <div aria-level="2" class="office-form-question-title" id="question1-title" role="heading">
        <span class="ordinal-number">1.</span>
        <span>What's your name?</span>
        <span class="required-star"></span>
        <div><span class="accessibility-reader-no-display" id="question1-required">Requer resposta</span></div>
        <div><span class="accessibility-reader-no-display" id="question1-questiontype">Texto de linha única</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="office-form-question-element">
    <div class="student-feedback-view-short-text-field-with-correctness">
      <div>
        <div class="office-form-textfield">
          <input class="office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control border-no-radius" aria-labelledby="question1-title question1-required question1-questiontype" placeholder="Insira sua resposta" spellcheck="true" maxlength="4000"
            value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```